# Associate Doc Library with Lists

Tags: list, document-library

Experts,

Not sure how to have a default document library for a SharePoint 2013 List.
So the moment, a user attach a document, the location to store the file is the default document library, rather showing the entire Site collection.

Please educate.

Comment: Can you please add some more details with example?

Answer (score 0):

A list and a library are two different things. If you attach a document to a list item, it will be stored as an attachment in the list item, not in a document library.  You may want to edit your question and explain what you would like to achieve. It seems that there is some misconception of SharePoint concepts, or of the terminology.

Comment: Teylyn, I want my List to be aligned with a document library. So user when click on upload document (one of the list field) its points them to the specific document library rather showing all possible libraries within the site collection. Hope that its makes much clearer.

Comment: Explain in what context the user clicks to upload a document. If you are using a list form to upload a document, it will be saved as an attachment to the list item. A document library is a different thing. Uploading a document to a library works by opening the dialog to upload a document. That dialog is typically found in a document library, not in a list field. Again: edit **your question** to provide this clarification. Then post a comment when you've done that.